# Inherent python abstract base class in django

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

I would like to make an generic module in python which uses data from a Django model, and use typing to document the interface. The module should be independent of the Django model. How should this by done in a pythonic way?

I'm thinking of using ABC class, the independent python file should then be something like (shape.py):

```
from abc import ABC


class Shape(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def height(self) -> float:
         pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def area(self) -> float:
         pass


class VolumeCalculation:
    def __init__(self, shape: Shape) -> None:
        self.shape = shape

    def volume(self) -> float
        return self.shape.area*self.shape.height
```

While the django model is defined in another file:

```
from django.db import models
from shape import Shape


class Box(models.Model, Shape):
    height= models.FloatField('height')
    area = models.FloatField('area')
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Alternatively I can remove the base class and construct VolumeCalculation with the needed parameters from Shape. But as the real object contains many parameters the list becomes quite long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to derive `Box` from `Shape` to make it a `Shape`, you can just [register it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register):

```
from django.db import models
from shape import Shape


class Box(models.Model):
    height= models.FloatField('height')
    area = models.FloatField('area')

Shape.register(Box)
```